# Visual Studio System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException Error

Tags: c#, ms-access

Hi Guys I am currently working on forms in Visual studio and one of my forms is
called "Add Assignment". However every time I launch the application and try to Add an assignment, I get left with a error message saying "You must enter a value in the 'ASSIGNMENT.BusinessID' field."

I assume this is because in my Assignment Access DataTable I have a column called BusinessID. And my code does not address BusinessID because I don't know how to automatically generate it through my code. Here is the code for adding Assignment in the Add Assignment form.

```
private void btnAddAssignment_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataRow newAssignmentRow = DC.dtAssignment.NewRow();
        if (txtAssignmentDescription.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("One or more fields is blank", "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                            MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            try
            {

                newAssignmentRow["AssignmentDescription"] = txtAssignmentDescription.Text;
                newAssignmentRow["AssignmentDate"] = dtpAssignmentDate.Value;
                newAssignmentRow["AssignmentFee"] = nudFee.Value;
                newAssignmentRow["Status"] = cboStatus.Text;
                DC.dtAssignment.Rows.Add(newAssignmentRow);
                MessageBox.Show("Employee added successfully", "Success");
                DC.UpdateAssignment();
                ClearFields();
            }
            catch (FormatException ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for Fee", "Error");
            }

        }
```

Also this is in my DataController. I think this is supposed to help generate a ID but I'm not sure.  [Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mBTew.png)
I would appreciate any help immensely. Thank you very much!

[DataBase Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xiPO2.png)

Comment: Please include the "visual-studio" tag only for questions about the VS environment itself.

Comment: What database are you using? Access? How is the table defined? Post the actual `CREATE TABLE` statement, not images of the data. The images don't show the field types. In Access, the AutoNumber field is used for automatically incrementing fields